# Interpretation of negative values in the results of LSA

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, topic-models, latent-semantic-analysis

How can I interpret the results of LSA?

From the following table, I can understand that documents 0 and 1 (dealing with cats) fall into Topic 2.

Document 4, which talks about both dog and cat, falls into Topic 2, this is because cat and white have greater weight in Topic 2.

Furthermore, documents 2 and 3, which talk about dogs, fall into Topic 1.

The negative numbers in the table come from the negative weights. But how can I interpret a negative weight and therefore a negative final value?

| ID | Clean document | Topic 1 | Topic 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | red cat | 0.3456 | 0.9856 |
| 1 | lazy cat | 0.3892 | 0.8674 |
| 2 | brown dog | 0.8612 | -0.4121 |
| 3 | old dog | 0.9888 | -0.3211 |
| 4 | cat white dog | 0.0524 | 0.9663 |